# Extracting Long text Data from SAP into Excel

Tags: sap-gui

I am working on a project to pull some data for a process and need to pull the text from an SAP task that is designated as long text. I need to click a button which opens a document that contains the long text as a paragraph. This data is contained in a Microsoft word-looking document which appears as a popup from the SAP interface.

The script recorder cannot be used in this situation since it is somewhat outside of SAP and therefore I cannot click on a field to record the data present.

When I try to record opening the document (pressing the long test button in SAP) it records a long string of gibberish and does not allow me to simply change from a .setfocus as would be seen when clicking on a field, to a .text in order to extract the statements to excel.

I am working on a project to pull some data for a process and need to pull the text from an SAP task that is designated as long text. I need to click a button which opens a document that contains the long text as a paragraph. This data is contained in a Microsoft word-looking document which appears as a popup from the SAP interface.

The script recorder cannot be used in this situation since it is somewhat outside of SAP and therefore I cannot click on a field to record the data present.

When I try to record opening the document (pressing the long test button in SAP) it records a long string of gibberish and does not allow me to simply change from a .setfocus as would be seen when clicking on a field, to a .text in order to extract the statements to excel.

Here is a piece of the recorded script when pressing the "long text view"  button. It is too large to paste the whole thing but it basically repeats. The code ends in a .press about 30,000 characters after this snippet.

Does anyone know the code associated with pulling long text data of this sort?

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAB_GROUP_10/tabp10\TAB10/ssubSUB_GROUP_10:SAPLIQS0:7210/tabsTAB_GROUP_20/tabp20\TAB03/ssubSUB_GROUP_20:SAPLIQS0:7125/tblSAPLIQS0MASSNAH_VIEWER2/btnQMICON-LTMASS[5,0]").setFocus

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAB_GROUP_10/tabp10\TAB10/ssubSUB_GROUP_10:SAPLIQS0:7210/tabsTAB_GROUP_20/tabp20\TAB03/ssubSUB_GROUP_20:SAPLIQS0:7125/tblSAPLIQS0MASSNAH_VIEWER2/btnQMICON-LTMASS[5,0]").press

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlSCMSW_CONTAINER_2102/shellcont/shell").setDocument 1,"e1xydGYxXGFkZWZsYW5nMTAyNVxhbnNpXGFuc2ljcGcxMjUyXHVjMVxhZGVmZjBcZGVmZjBcc3RzaGZkYmNoMFxzdHNoZmxvY2gzN1xzdHNoZmhpY2gzN1xzdHNoZmJpMFxkZWZsYW5nMTAzM1xkZWZsYW5nZmUxMDMzXHRoZW1lbGFuZzEwMzNcdGhlbWVsYW5nZmUwXHRoZW1lbGFuZ2NzMHtcZm9udHRibHtcZjBcZmJpZGkgXGZyb21hblxmY2hhcnNldDBcZnBycTJ7XCpccGFub3NlIDAyMDIwNjAzMDUwNDA1MDIwMzA0fVRpbWVzIE5ldyBSb21hbjt9e1xmMlxmYmlkaSBcZm1vZGVyblxmY2hhcnNldDBcZnBycTF7XCpccGFub3NlIDAyMDcwMzA5MDIwMjA1MDIwNDA0fUNvdXJpZXIgTmV3O30NCntcZjJcZmJpZGkgXGZtb2Rlcm5cZmNoYXJzZXQwXGZwcnExe1wqXHBhbm9zZSAwMjA3MDMwOTAyMDIwNTAyMDQwNH1Db3VyaWVyIE5ldzt9e1xmMzdcZmJpZGkgXGZzd2lzc1xmY2hhcnNldDBcZnBycTJ7XCpccGFub3NlIDAyMGYwNTAyMDIwMjA0MDMwMjA0fUNhbGlicmk7fXtcZmxvbWFqb3JcZjMxNTAwXGZiaWRpIFxmcm9tYW5cZmNoYXJzZXQwXGZwcnEye1wqXHBhbm9zZSAwMjAyMDYwMzA1MDQwNTAyMDMwNH1UaW1lcyBOZXcgUm9tYW47fQ0Ke1xmZGJtYWpvclxmMzE1MDFcZmJpZGkgXGZyb21hblxmY2hhcnNldDBcZnBycTJ7XCpccGFub3NlIDAyMDIwNjAzMDUwNDA1MDIwMzA0fVRpbWVzIE5ldyBSb21hbjt9e1xmaGltYWpvclxmMzE1MDJcZmJpZGkgXGZzd2lzc1xmY2hhcnNldDBcZnBycTJ7XCpccGFub3NlIDAyMGYwMzAyMDIwMjA0MDMwMjA0fUNhbGlicmkgTGlnaHQ7fQ0Ke1xmYmltYWpvclxmMzE1MDNcZmJpZGkgXGZyb21hblxmY2hhcnNldDBcZnBycTJ7XCpccGFub3NlIDAyMDIwNjAzMDUwNDA1MDIwMzA0fVRpbWVzIE5ldyBSb21hbjt9e1xmbG9taW5vclxmMzE1MDRcZmJpZGkgXGZyb21hblxmY2hhcnNldDBcZnBycTJ7XCpccGFub3NlIDAyMDIwNjAzMDUwNDA1MDIwMzA0fVRpbWVzIE5ldyBSb21hbjt9DQp7XGZkYm1pbm9yXGYzMTUwNVxmYmlkaSBcZnJvbWFuXGZjaGFyc2V0MFxmcHJxMntcKlxwYW5vc2UgMDIwMjA2MDMwNTA0MDUwMjAzMDR9VGltZXMgTmV3IFJvbWFuO317XGZoaW1pbm9yXGYzMTUwNlxmYmlkaSBcZnN3aXNzXGZjaGFyc2V0MFxmcHJxMntcKlxwYW5vc2UgMDIwZjA1MDIwMjAyMDQwMzAyMDR9Q2FsaWJyaTt9DQp7XGZiaW1pbm9yXGYzMTUwN1xmYmlkaSBcZnJvbWFuXGZjaGFyc2V0MFxmcHJxMntcKlxwYW5vc2UgMDIwMjA2MDMwNTA0MDUwMjAzMDR9VGltZXMgTmV3IFJvbWFuO317XGY0OVxmYmlkaSBcZnJvbWFuXGZjaGFyc2V0MjM4XGZwcnEyIFRpbWVzIE5ldyBSb21hbiBDRTt9e1xmNTBcZmJpZGkgXGZyb21hblxmY2hhcnNldDIwNFxmcHJxMiBUaW1lcyBOZXcgUm9tYW4gQ3lyO30NCntcZjUyXGZiaWRpIFxmcm9tYW5cZmNoYXJzZXQxNjFcZnBycTIgVGltZXMgTmV3IFJvbWFuIEdyZWVrO317XGY1M1xmYmlkaSBcZnJvbWFuXGZjaGFyc2V0MTYyXGZwcnEyIFRpbWVzIE5ldyBSb21hbiBUdXI7fXtcZjU0XGZiaWRpIFxmcm9tYW5cZmNoYXJzZXQxNzdcZnBycTIgVGltZXMgTmV3IFJvbWFuIChIZWJyZXcpO317XGY1NVxmYmlkaSBcZnJvbWFuXGZjaGFyc2V0MTc4XGZwcnEyIFRpbWVzIE5ldyBSb21hbiAoQXJhYmljKTt9DQp7XGY1NlxmYmlkaSBcZnJvbWFuXGZjaGFyc2V0MTg2XGZwcnEyIFRpbWVzIE5ldyBSb21hbiBCYWx0aWM7fXtcZjU3XGZiaWRpIFxmcm9tYW5cZmNoYXJzZXQxNjNcZnBycTIgVGltZXMgTmV3IFJvbWFuIChWaWV0bmFtZXNlKTt9e1xmNjlcZmJpZGkgXGZtb2Rlcm5cZmNoYXJzZXQyMzhcZnBycTEgQ291cmllciBOZXcgQ0U7fXtcZjcwXGZiaWRpIFxmbW9kZXJuXGZjaGFyc2V0MjA0XGZwcnExIENvdXJpZXIgTmV3IEN5cjt9DQp7XGY3MlxmYmlkaSBcZm1vZGVyblxmY2hhcnNldDE2MVxmcHJxMSBDb3VyaWVyIE5ldyBHcmVlazt9e1xmNzNcZmJpZGkgXGZtb2Rlcm5cZmNoYXJzZXQxNjJcZnBycTEgQ291cmllciBOZXcgVHVyO317XGY3NFxmYmlkaSBcZm1vZGVyblxmY2hhcnNldDE3N1xmcHJxMSBDb3VyaWVyIE5ldyAoSGVicmV3KTt9e1xmNzVcZmJpZGkgXGZtb2Rlcm5cZmNoYXJzZXQxNzhcZnBycTEgQ291cmllciBOZXcgKEFyYWJpYyk7fQ0Ke1xmNzZcZmJpZGkgXGZtb2Rlcm5cZmNoYXJzZXQxODZcZnBycTEgQ291cmllciBOZXcgQmFsdGljO317XGY3N1xmYmlkaSBcZm1vZGVyblxmY2hhcnNldDE2M1xmcHJxMSBDb3VyaWVyIE5ldyAoVmlldG5hbWVzZSk7fXtcZjY5XGZiaWRpIFxmbW9kZXJuXGZjaGFyc2V0MjM4XGZwcnExIENvdXJpZXIgTmV3IENFO317XGY3MFxmYmlkaSBcZm1vZGVyblxmY2hhcnNldDIwNFxmcHJxMSBDb3VyaWVyIE5ldyBDeXI7fQ0Ke1xmNzJcZmJpZGkgXGZtb2Rlcm5cZmNoYXJzZXQxNjFcZnBycTEgQ291cmllciBOZXcgR3JlZWs7fXtcZjczXGZiaWRpIFxmbW9kZXJuXGZjaGFyc2V0MTYyXGZwcnExIENvdXJpZXIgTmV3IFR1cjt9e1xmNzRcZmJpZGkgXGZtb2Rlcm5cZmNoYXJzZXQxNzdcZnBycTEgQ291cmllciBOZXcgKEhlYnJldyk7fXtcZjc1XGZiaWRpIFxmbW9kZXJuXGZjaGFyc2V0MTc4XGZwcnExIENvdXJpZXIgTmV3IChBcmFiaWMpO30NCntcZjc2XGZiaWRpIFxmbW9kZXJuXGZjaGFyc2V0MTg2XGZwcnExIENvdXJpZXIgTmV3IEJhbHRpYzt9e1xmNzdcZmJpZGkgXGZtb2Rlcm5cZmNoYXJzZXQxNjNcZnBycTEgQ291cmllciBOZXcgKFZpZXRuYW1lc2UpO317XGY0MTlcZmJpZGkgXGZzd2lzc1xmY2hhcnNldDIzOFxmcHJxMiBDYWxpYnJpIENFO317XGY0MjBcZmJpZGkgXGZzd2lzc1xmY2hhcnNldDIwNFxmcHJxMiBDYWxpYnJpIEN5cjt9DQp7XGY0MjJcZmJpZGkgXGZzd2lzc1xmY2hhcnNldDE2MVxmcHJxMiBDYWxpYnJpIEdyZWVrO317XGY0MjNcZmJpZGkgXGZzd2lzc1xmY2hhcnNldDE2MlxmcHJxMiBDYWxpYnJpIFR1cjt9e1xmNDI2XGZiaWRpIFxmc3dpc3NcZmNoYXJzZXQxODZcZnBycTIgQ2FsaWJyaSBCYWx0aWM7fXtcZjQyN1xmYmlkaSBcZnN3aXNzXGZjaGFyc2V0MTYzXGZwcnEyIENhbGlicmkgKFZpZXRuYW1lc2UpO30NCntcZmxvbWFqb3JcZjMxNTA4XGZiaWRpIFxmcm9tYW5cZmNoYXJzZXQyMzhcZnBycTIgVGltZXMgTmV3IFJvbWFuIENFO317XGZsb21ham9yXGYzMTUwOVxmYmlkaSBcZnJvbWFuXGZjaGFyc2V0MjA0XGZwcnEyIFRpbWVzIE5ldyBSb21hbiBDeXI7fXtcZmxvbWFqb3JcZjMxNTExXGZiaWRpIFxmcm9tYW5cZmNoYXJzZXQxNjFcZnBycTIgVGltZXMgTmV3IFJvbWFuIEdyZWVrO30NCntcZmxvbWFqb3JcZjMxNTEyXGZiaWRpIFxmcm9tYW5cZmNoYXJzZXQxNjJcZnBycTIgVGltZXMgTmV3IFJvbWFuIFR1cjt9e1xmbG9tYWpvclxmMzE1MTNcZmJpZGkgXGZyb21hblxmY2hhcnNldDE3N1xmcHJxMiBUaW1lcyBOZXcgUm9tYW4gKEhlYnJldyk7fXtcZmxvbWFqb3JcZjMxNTE0XGZiaWRpIFxmcm9tYW5cZmNoYXJzZXQxNzhcZnBycTIgVGltZXMgTmV3IFJvbWFuIChBcmFiaWMpO30NCntcZmxvbWFqb3JcZjMxNTE1XGZiaWRpIFxmcm9tYW5cZmNoYXJzZXQxODZcZnBycTIgVGltZXMgTmV3IFJvbWFuIEJhbHRpYzt9e1xmbG9tYWpvclxmMzE1MTZcZmJpZGkgXGZyb21hblxmY2hhcnNldDE2M1xmcHJxMiBUaW1lcyBOZXcgUm9tYW4gKFZpZXRuYW1lc2UpO317XGZkYm1ham9yXGYzMTUxOFxmYmlkaSBcZnJvbWFuXGZjaGFyc2V0MjM4XGZwcnEyIFRpbWVzIE5ldyBSb21hbiBDRTt9DQp7XGZkYm1ham9yXGYzMTUxOVxmYmlkaSBcZnJvbWFuXGZjaGFyc2V0MjA0XGZwcnEyIFRpbWVzIE5ldyBSb21hbiBDeXI7fXtcZmRibWFqb3JcZjMxNTIxXGZiaWRpIFxmcm9tYW5cZmNoYXJzZXQxNjFcZnBycTIgVGltZXMgTmV3IFJvbWFuIEdyZWVrO317XGZkYm1ham9yXGYzMTUyMlxmYmlkaSBcZnJvbWFuXGZjaGFyc2V0MTYyXGZwcnEyIFRpbWVzIE5ldyBSb21hbiBUdXI7fQ0Ke1xmZGJtYWpvclxmMzE1MjNcZmJpZGkgXGZyb21hblxmY2hhcnNldDE3N1xmcHJxMiBUaW1lcyBOZXcgUm9tYW4gKEhlYnJldyk7fXtcZmRibWFqb3JcZjMxNTI0XGZiaWRpIFxmcm9tYW5cZmNoYXJzZXQxNzhcZnBycTIgVGltZXMgTmV3IFJvbWFuIChBcmFiaWMpO317XGZkYm1ham9yXGYzMTUyNVxmYmlkaSBcZnJvbWFuXGZjaGFyc2V0MTg2XGZwcnEyIFRpbWVzIE5ldyBSb21hbiBCYWx0aWM7fQ0Ke1xmZGJtYWpvclxmMzE1MjZcZmJpZGkgXGZyb21hblxmY2hhcnNldDE2M1xmcHJxMiBUaW1lcyBOZXcgUm9tYW4gKFZpZXRuYW1lc2UpO317XGZoaW1ham9yXGYzMTUyOFxmYmlkaSBcZnN3aXNzXGZjaGFyc2V0MjM4XGZwcnEyIENhbGlicmkgTGlnaHQgQ0U7fXtcZmhpbWFqb3JcZjMxNTI5XGZiaWRpIFxmc3dpc3NcZmNoYXJzZXQyMDRcZnBycTIgQ2FsaWJyaSBMaWdodCBDeXI7fQ0Ke1xmaGltYWpvclxmMzE1MzFcZmJpZGkgXGZzd2lzc1xmY2hhcnNldDE2MVxmcHJxMiBDYWxpYnJpIExpZ2h0IEdyZWVrO317XGZoaW1ham9yXGYzMTUzMlxmYmlkaSBcZnN3aXNzXGZjaGFyc2V0MTYyXGZwcnEyIENhbGlicmkgTGlnaHQgVHVyO317XGZoaW1ham9yXGYzMTUzNVxmYmlkaSBcZnN3aXNzXGZjaGFyc2V0MTg2XGZwcnEyIENhbGli
```

Comment: Well it is hard to help you when we do not have code.  You can paste, if it is not under any NDA, here https://pastebin.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to get what I need. Once you open the long text, you will be brought to a Microsoft word like document. At the top of your SAP bar, you will see a goto option. Click that and then click configure editor. Uncheck Graphical PC Editor. You will find that the interface will change and now each line is treated as a field. Script recorder works well with this format so you can record clicking the long text button to open the text, as well as each line in the long text document. I just created a loop to add each line together until the paragraph was complete.